# Can I request that someone look over my legal code?

Tags: discussion, scope

I wrote two licenses under which I will place my software and art, and I want to make sure they're good enough for what they're intended to do. **Is it OK to post them here for review?**

Comment: I know that this is a meta post but especially since you're probably not going to post your real question now, I'd like to say that you'll do your users and yourself a favor by sticking with a well-known public license rather than inventing your own. Look at the license zoo maintained by the [OSI](http://opensource.org/licenses/) and the [FSF](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Based on the guidelines in the [Help Center](/help/on-topic), questions asking to review license text would be off-topic, as it's not code.

If you have a specific question about a legal principle related to licensing, you could ask on [Open Source](//opensource.stackexchange.com/) (assuming that it's related to open-source software) or [Law](//law.stackexchange.com/).

Note, however, that no Stack Exchange site will give you personalized legal advice.  That means that if you're looking for someone to proofread or bulletproof license terms that you wrote, you should hire a lawyer.

Answer (score 21):

#### No.

Code Review is for the review of "code" in the sense of interpreted or compiled programming languages.  Not for any other sort of "code" such as "legal code".

Comment: @DamienH Compiled or interpreted by a program or hardware. This is why Code Review is a bad fit for legal code.